# When a Dialog springs up, is the Activity behind it still technically in foreground?

Tags: android, nfc, android-alertdialog

I'm thinking of implementing a feature, but don't want it to clash with NFC use in my app. NFC takes hold of the foreground activity, and if any other phone with NFC on is within centimeters, sends over the data. I don't want this to happen when a user creates a post, and I'm thinking about having a dialog window for the user to create a post. That being said, does having a Dialog up in front of an Activity mean the Activity is no longer in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to NFC foreground dispatch: A dialog (fragment or "regular" dialog) will not influence the foreground dispatch system. The activity will remain registered to receive NFC events.